# Install SQL Server 2014 in windows 10 not installing database engine and some features?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, installation, windows-10

```
  Overall summary:
   Final result:                  Failed: see details below
   Exit code (Decimal):           -2068054016
   Start time:                    2016-03-27 17:00:55
   End time:                      2016-03-27 17:42:06
   Requested action:              Install

   Setup completed with required actions for features.
   Troubleshooting information for those features:
    Next step for Adv_SSMS:        Use the following information to resolve the error, and then try the setup process again.
    Next step for Conn:            Use the following information to resolve the error, and then try the setup process again.
    Next step for SDK:             Use the following information to resolve the error, and then try the setup process again.
    Next step for BC:              Use the following information to resolve the error, and then try the setup process again.
    Next step for SSMS:            Use the following information to resolve the error, and then try the setup process again.
    Next step for SQLEngine:       Use the following information to resolve the error, and then try the setup process again.
    Next step for DQ:              Use the following information to resolve the error, and then try the setup process again.
    Next step for FullText:        Use the following information to resolve the error, and then try the setup process again.
    Next step for Replication:     Use the following information to resolve the error, and then try the setup process again.
    Next step for IS:              Use the following information to resolve the error, and then try the setup process again.
    Next step for Browser:         Use the following information to resolve the error, uninstall this feature, and then run the setup process again.
    Next step for Writer:          Use the following information to resolve the error, and then try the setup process again.
   Next step for SNAC:            Use the following information to resolve the error, and then try the setup process again.
   Next step for SNAC_SDK:        Use the following information to resolve the error, and then try the setup process again.


 Machine Properties:
   Machine name:                  DESKTOP-CSBHRCD
   Machine processor count:       4
   OS version:                    Windows 8
   OS service pack:               
   OS region:                     United States
   OS language:                   English (United States)
   OS architecture:               x64
   Process architecture:          64 Bit
   OS clustered:                  No

   Product features discovered:
   Product              Instance             Instance ID                      Feature                                  Language             Edition              Version         Clustered  Configured

  Package properties:
   Description:                   Microsoft SQL Server 2014 
   ProductName:                   SQL Server 2014
   Type:                          RTM
   Version:                       12
   Installation location:         G:\x64\setup\
   Installation edition:          Enterprise Edition: Core-based Licensing

   Slipstream:                    True
   SP Level                       1

   Product Update Status:
    Success: KB 3058865

  Product Updates Selected for Installation:
    Title:                         Microsoft SQL Server 2014  with SP1
    Knowledge Based Article:       KB 3058865
    Version:                       12.1.4100.0
    Architecture:                  x64
    Language:                      1033

    Update Source:                 Slipstream


   User Input Settings:
     ACTION:                        Install
     ADDCURRENTUSERASSQLADMIN:      false
     AGTSVCACCOUNT:                 NT Service\SQLAgent$MSSQL
     AGTSVCPASSWORD:                *****
     AGTSVCSTARTUPTYPE:             Manual
     ASBACKUPDIR:                   Backup
     ASCOLLATION:                   Latin1_General_CI_AS
     ASCONFIGDIR:                   Config
     ASDATADIR:                     Data
     ASLOGDIR:                      Log
     ASPROVIDERMSOLAP:              1
     ASSERVERMODE:                  MULTIDIMENSIONAL
     ASSVCACCOUNT:                  <empty>
     ASSVCPASSWORD:                 <empty>
     ASSVCSTARTUPTYPE:              Automatic
     ASSYSADMINACCOUNTS:            <empty>
     ASTEMPDIR:                     Temp
     BROWSERSVCSTARTUPTYPE:         Automatic
     CLTCTLRNAME:                   <empty>
     CLTRESULTDIR:                  <empty>
     CLTSTARTUPTYPE:                0
     CLTSVCACCOUNT:                 <empty>
     CLTSVCPASSWORD:                <empty>
     CLTWORKINGDIR:                 <empty>
     COMMFABRICENCRYPTION:          0
     COMMFABRICNETWORKLEVEL:        0
     COMMFABRICPORT:                0
     CONFIGURATIONFILE:             C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Setup Bootstrap\Log\20160327_170034\ConfigurationFile.ini
     CTLRSTARTUPTYPE:               0
     CTLRSVCACCOUNT:                <empty>
     CTLRSVCPASSWORD:               <empty>
     CTLRUSERS:                     <empty>
     ENABLERANU:                    false
     ENU:                           true
     ERRORREPORTING:                false
     FEATURES:                      SQLENGINE, REPLICATION, FULLTEXT, DQ,   DQC, CONN, IS, BC, SDK, BOL, SSMS, ADV_SSMS, SNAC_SDK, MDS
     FILESTREAMLEVEL:               0
     FILESTREAMSHARENAME:           <empty>
     FTSVCACCOUNT:                  NT Service\MSSQLFDLauncher$MSSQL
     FTSVCPASSWORD:                 <empty>
     HELP:                          false
     IACCEPTSQLSERVERLICENSETERMS:  true
     INDICATEPROGRESS:              false
     INSTALLSHAREDDIR:              C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Servers\
     INSTALLSHAREDWOWDIR:           C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Servers\
     INSTALLSQLDATADIR:             <empty>
     INSTANCEDIR:                   C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Servers\
     INSTANCEID:                    MSSQL
     INSTANCENAME:                  MSSQL
     ISSVCACCOUNT:                  NT Service\MsDtsServer120
     ISSVCPASSWORD:                 <empty>
     ISSVCSTARTUPTYPE:              Automatic
     MATRIXCMBRICKCOMMPORT:         0
     MATRIXCMSERVERNAME:            <empty>
     MATRIXNAME:                    <empty>
      NPENABLED:                     0
     PID:                           *****
    QUIET:                         false
     QUIETSIMPLE:                   false
    ROLE:                          <empty>
    RSINSTALLMODE:                 DefaultNativeMode
    RSSHPINSTALLMODE:              DefaultSharePointMode
    RSSVCACCOUNT:                  <empty>
     RSSVCPASSWORD:                 <empty>
    RSSVCSTARTUPTYPE:              Automatic
    SAPWD:                         *****
    SECURITYMODE:                  SQL
    SQLBACKUPDIR:                  <empty>
   SQLCOLLATION:                  Latin1_General_CI_AI
   SQLSVCACCOUNT:                 NT Service\MSSQL$MSSQL
   SQLSVCPASSWORD:                <empty>
   SQLSVCSTARTUPTYPE:             Automatic
   SQLSYSADMINACCOUNTS:           DESKTOP-CSBHRCD\Darrell
   SQLTEMPDBDIR:                  <empty>
   SQLTEMPDBLOGDIR:               <empty>
   SQLUSERDBDIR:                  <empty>
   SQLUSERDBLOGDIR:               <empty>
   SQMREPORTING:                  false
   TCPENABLED:                    1
   UIMODE:                        Normal
   UpdateEnabled:                 true
   UpdateSource:                  Slipstream
   USEMICROSOFTUPDATE:            false
   X86:                           false

     Configuration file:            C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Setup Bootstrap\Log\20160327_170034\ConfigurationFile.ini

  Detailed results:
    Feature:                       Management Tools - Complete
    Status:                        Failed: see logs for details
    Reason for failure:            An error occurred for a dependency of the feature causing the setup process for the feature to fail.
    Next Step:                     Use the following information to resolve the error, and then try the setup process again.
    Component name:                SQL Server Native Client Access Component
    Component error code:          -2147483648
    Component log file:            C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Setup Bootstrap\Log\20160327_170034\sqlncli_Cpu64_1.log
    Error description:             A previous installation required a reboot of the machine for changes to take effect.  To proceed, restart your computer and then run Setup again.
    Error help link:               http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?LinkId=20476&ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&EvtSrc=setup.rll&EvtID=50000&ProdVer=12.0.4100.1&EvtType=sqlncli.msi%40CA_ErrorPendingReboot%40-2147483648

       Feature:                       Client Tools Connectivity
       Status:                        Failed: see logs for details
       Reason for failure:            An error occurred for a dependency of the feature causing the setup process for the feature to fail.
       Next Step:                     Use the following information to resolve the error, and then try the setup process again.
      Component name:                SQL Server Native Client Access Component
      Component error code:          -2147483648
      Component log file:            C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Setup Bootstrap\Log\20160327_170034\sqlncli_Cpu64_1.log
      Error description:             A previous installation required a reboot of the machine for changes to take effect.  To proceed, restart your computer and then run Setup again.
      Error help link:               http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?LinkId=20476&ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&EvtSrc=setup.rll&EvtID=50000&ProdVer=12.0.4100.1&EvtType=sqlncli.msi%40CA_ErrorPendingReboot%40-2147483648

     Feature:                       Client Tools SDK
     Status:                        Failed: see logs for details
     Reason for failure:            An error occurred for a dependency of the feature causing the setup process for the feature to fail.
     Next Step:                     Use the following information to resolve the error, and then try the setup process again.
     Component name:                SQL Server Native Client Access Component
     Component error code:          -2147483648
     Component log file:            C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Setup Bootstrap\Log\20160327_170034\sqlncli_Cpu64_1.log
     Error description:             A previous installation required a reboot of the machine for changes to take effect.  To proceed, restart your computer and then run Setup again.
     Error help link:               http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?LinkId=20476&ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&EvtSrc=setup.rll&EvtID=50000&ProdVer=12.0.4100.1&EvtType=sqlncli.msi%40CA_ErrorPendingReboot%40-2147483648

    Feature:                       Client Tools Backwards Compatibility
    Status:                        Failed: see logs for details
    Reason for failure:            An error occurred for a dependency of the feature causing the setup process for the feature to fail.
    Next Step:                     Use the following information to resolve the error, and then try the setup process again.
   Component name:                SQL Server Native Client Access Component
   Component error code:          -2147483648
   Component log file:            C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Setup Bootstrap\Log\20160327_170034\sqlncli_Cpu64_1.log
   Error description:             A previous installation required a reboot of the machine for changes to take effect.  To proceed, restart your computer and then run Setup again.
    Error help link:               http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?LinkId=20476&ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&EvtSrc=setup.rll&EvtID=50000&ProdVer=12.0.4100.1&EvtType=sqlncli.msi%40CA_ErrorPendingReboot%40-2147483648

    Feature:                       Management Tools - Basic
    Status:                        Failed: see logs for details
    Reason for failure:            An error occurred for a dependency of the feature causing the setup process for the feature to fail.
    Next Step:                     Use the following information to resolve the error, and then try the setup process again.
      Component name:                SQL Server Native Client Access Component
     Component error code:          -2147483648
     Component log file:            C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Setup Bootstrap\Log\20160327_170034\sqlncli_Cpu64_1.log
     Error description:             A previous installation required a reboot of the machine for changes to take effect.  To proceed, restart your computer and then run Setup again.
     Error help link:               http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?LinkId=20476&ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&EvtSrc=setup.rll&EvtID=50000&ProdVer=12.0.4100.1&EvtType=sqlncli.msi%40CA_ErrorPendingReboot%40-2147483648

      Feature:                       Database Engine Services
      Status:                        Failed: see logs for details
       Reason for failure:            An error occurred for a dependency of the feature causing the setup process for the feature to fail.
    Next Step:                     Use the following information to resolve the error, and then try the setup process again.
    Component name:                SQL Server Native Client Access Component
    Component error code:          -2147483648
    Component log file:            C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Setup Bootstrap\Log\20160327_170034\sqlncli_Cpu64_1.log
   Error description:             A previous installation required a reboot of the machine for changes to take effect.  To proceed, restart your computer and then run Setup again.
    Error help link:               http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?LinkId=20476&ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&EvtSrc=setup.rll&EvtID=50000&ProdVer=12.0.4100.1&EvtType=sqlncli.msi%40CA_ErrorPendingReboot%40-2147483648

    Feature:                       Data Quality Services
    Status:                        Failed: see logs for details
    Reason for failure:            An error occurred for a dependency of the feature causing the setup process for the feature to fail.
    Next Step:                     Use the following information to resolve the error, and then try the setup process again.
   Component name:                SQL Server Native Client Access Component
   Component error code:          -2147483648
   Component log file:            C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Setup Bootstrap\Log\20160327_170034\sqlncli_Cpu64_1.log
   Error description:             A previous installation required a reboot of the machine for changes to take effect.  To proceed, restart your computer and then run Setup again.
    Error help link:               http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?LinkId=20476&ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&EvtSrc=setup.rll&EvtID=50000&ProdVer=12.0.4100.1&EvtType=sqlncli.msi%40CA_ErrorPendingReboot%40-2147483648

    Feature:                       Full-Text and Semantic Extractions for Search
    Status:                        Failed: see logs for details
    Reason for failure:            An error occurred for a dependency of the feature causing the setup process for the feature to fail.
    Next Step:                     Use the following information to resolve the error, and then try the setup process again.
    Component name:                SQL Server Native Client Access Component
    Component error code:          -2147483648
    Component log file:            C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Setup Bootstrap\Log\20160327_170034\sqlncli_Cpu64_1.log
    Error description:             A previous installation required a reboot of the machine for changes to take effect.  To proceed, restart your computer and then run Setup again.
    Error help link:               http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?LinkId=20476&ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&EvtSrc=setup.rll&EvtID=50000&ProdVer=12.0.4100.1&EvtType=sqlncli.msi%40CA_ErrorPendingReboot%40-2147483648

    Feature:                       SQL Server Replication
    Status:                        Failed: see logs for details
    Reason for failure:            An error occurred for a dependency of the feature causing the setup process for the feature to fail.
    Next Step:                     Use the following information to resolve the error, and then try the setup process again.
    Component name:                SQL Server Native Client Access Component
    Component error code:          -2147483648
    Component log file:            C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Setup Bootstrap\Log\20160327_170034\sqlncli_Cpu64_1.log
    Error description:             A previous installation required a reboot of the machine for changes to take effect.  To proceed, restart your computer and then run Setup again.
    Error help link:               http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?LinkId=20476&ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&EvtSrc=setup.rll&EvtID=50000&ProdVer=12.0.4100.1&EvtType=sqlncli.msi%40CA_ErrorPendingReboot%40-2147483648

      Feature:                       Master Data Services
      Status:                        Passed

       Feature:                       Integration Services
       Status:                        Failed: see logs for details
        Reason for failure:            An error occurred for a dependency of the feature causing the setup process for the feature to fail.
        Next Step:                     Use the following information to resolve the error, and then try the setup process again.
      Component name:                SQL Server Native Client Access Component
      Component error code:          -2147483648
      Component log file:            C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Setup Bootstrap\Log\20160327_170034\sqlncli_Cpu64_1.log
      Error description:             A previous installation required a reboot of the machine for changes to take effect.  To proceed, restart your computer and then run Setup again.
      Error help link:               http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?LinkId=20476&ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&EvtSrc=setup.rll&EvtID=50000&ProdVer=12.0.4100.1&EvtType=sqlncli.msi%40CA_ErrorPendingReboot%40-2147483648

      Feature:                       Data Quality Client
      Status:                        Passed

      Feature:                       SQL Browser
      Status:                        Failed: see logs for details
      Reason for failure:            An error occurred during the setup process of the feature.
      Next Step:                     Use the following information to resolve the error, uninstall this feature, and then run the setup process again.
     Component name:                SQL Server Browser
     Component error code:          0x84BB0001
      Error description:             SQL Server Browser configuration for feature 'SQL_Browser_Redist_SqlBrowser_Cpu32' was cancelled by user after a previous installation failure. The last attempted step: Starting the SQL Server Browser service 'SQLBrowser', and waiting for up to '900' seconds for the process to complete. .
       Error help link:               http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?LinkId=20476&ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&EvtSrc=setup.rll&EvtID=50000&ProdVer=12.0.4100.1&EvtType=0x4F9BEA51%400xD3BEBD98%401211%401&EvtType=0x4F9BEA51%400xD3BEBD98%401211%401

     Feature:                       Documentation Components
     Status:                        Passed

      Feature:                       SQL Writer
      Status:                        Failed: see logs for details
      Reason for failure:            An error occurred during the setup process of the feature.
      Next Step:                     Use the following information to resolve the error, and then try the setup process again.
      Component name:                SQL Server Writer Component
      Component error code:          -2147483648
      Component log file:            C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Setup Bootstrap\Log\20160327_170034\SqlWriter_Cpu64_1.log
      Error description:             A previous installation required a reboot of the machine for changes to take effect.  To proceed, restart your computer and then run Setup again.
      Error help link:               http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?LinkId=20476&ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&EvtSrc=setup.rll&EvtID=50000&ProdVer=12.0.4100.1&EvtType=SqlWriter.msi%40CA_ErrorPendingReboot%40-2147483648

     Feature:                       SQL Client Connectivity
     Status:                        Failed: see logs for details
     Reason for failure:            An error occurred during the setup process of the feature.
      Next Step:                     Use the following information to resolve the error, and then try the setup process again.
     Component name:                SQL Server Native Client Access Component
     Component error code:          -2147483648
     Component log file:            C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Setup Bootstrap\Log\20160327_170034\sqlncli_Cpu64_1.log
     Error description:             A previous installation required a reboot of the machine for changes to take effect.  To proceed, restart your computer and then run Setup again.
      Error help link:               http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?LinkId=20476&ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&EvtSrc=setup.rll&EvtID=50000&ProdVer=12.0.4100.1&EvtType=sqlncli.msi%40CA_ErrorPendingReboot%40-2147483648

      Feature:                       SQL Client Connectivity SDK
      Status:                        Failed: see logs for details
     Reason for failure:            An error occurred during the setup process of the feature.
      Next Step:                     Use the following information to resolve the error, and then try the setup process again.
      Component name:                SQL Server Native Client Access Component
     Component error code:          -2147483648
     Component log file:            C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Setup Bootstrap\Log\20160327_170034\sqlncli_Cpu64_1.log
     Error description:             A previous installation required a reboot of the machine for changes to take effect.  To proceed, restart your computer and then run Setup again.
     Error help link:               http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?LinkId=20476&ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&EvtSrc=setup.rll&EvtID=50000&ProdVer=12.0.4100.1&EvtType=sqlncli.msi%40CA_ErrorPendingReboot%40-2147483648

      Feature:                       Setup Support Files
      Status:                        Passed

      Rules with failures:

      Global rules:

      Scenario specific rules:

       Rules report file:               C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Setup Bootstrap\Log\20160327_170034\SystemConfigurationCheck_Report.htm
```

> So as per the suggestion i deleted all sql files and tried to reinstall again.This was the error log

[![error on command propt on running sqlcmd -L][1]][1]

[![enter image description here][1]][1]
I am trying to install sql server 2014 along with visual studio.I had already installed sql server **but had installed all features available.But then i uninstalled it so that i can install select features.**
**After many trials on reinstalling ,database engine and server replication are still not being installed**(all features or select features installation does not work)

After some research **i cleared the pendingFileRenameOptions in regedit** but it wont work.
On opening ssms , i get the error in attachment on connecting.

[image: error on installation - named instance]

Answer (score 1):

Since we don't know what happened with your original installation, i.e. whether it was successful or not) it is difficult to pin down the exact issue.

I am sure SQL Server Database Engine has never been successfully installed, so is not eligible to repair. Also, it could be an SA or Service Account corruption Issue. You really need to be re-installing SQL Server fresh and not repairing.

So you could try to do a fresh install, but first I would uninstall anything related to SQL Server by going to Add/Remove Programs. Have a look at this link [Uninstall SQL Server](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms143412.aspx) for instructions on how to do a full uninstallation.

Check Services, to ensure there are no existing services related to SQL Server.

Then, I would do a complete reinstall, not a repair, and I would do it as a new Named Instance. Follow the installation through and see how you get on.

Make sure you are an administrator on the machine, and pay very special attention to the service account page of the installation. For this, make sure the SQL Service is running as the default NETWORK account. If it has picked up an account that is not eligible to start the service as part of the installation you'll get issues.

In short, you appear to be repairing something that either doesn't exist or is not stable to repair. You need to ensure any remnants of a previous install is removed fully and then start again.